# Why N-Queens Problem is not used as experiment in CSP thesis?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, constraint-satisfaction, constraint-programming, backtracking

I am studying CSP for my master thesis. I found that many thesis based on CSP described N-Queens as an introductory and they actually do experiment on random CSP problems.

If so,when I do master thesis in CSP,it is reasonable to experiment algorithms with N-Queens.

How can N-Queens problem be changed CSP parameters like Tightness,Constraint Density to experiment?

I wonder why many researchers test their CSP algorithms with Zebra problem, sudoku ,random CSP but why not N-Queens problem? Is N-Queens problem with CSP does not give better results?

Answer (score 1):

n-queens problem can be solved quite efficiently with a very simple algorithm (finding *all* solutions takes ages, because the number grows exponentially).

Getting anywhere near that efficiency with a general method is impossible.

Comment: What do you exactly means getting anywhere ?